# In AppleScript, what is the "ctxt" variable class?

Tags: macos, applescript, text

In trying to learn about data types in AppleScript, I referenced these web pages:

http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/computing/as_types/as_data_types.html

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24695

However, when I return the class of some of my AppleScript variables, I am given the class of "ctxt". Obviously, "txt" is short for "text". But "ctxt" is not mentioned in the above guides.

Comment: Do you realize your _code_ allows for an erroneous _time_ to be entered?

Comment: Can you please specify?

Comment: Here's an example: `--> {text returned:"99:99 pm", button returned:"OK"}`

Comment: Yes, thank you for bringing that to my attention but that is a separate process. In the code above, the goal is to solely ensure that the user entered numbers for the time. I have more code that checks to make sure the hour is under 12, minutes under 60, period is am or pm, etc. I didn't want to post everything because the other sections are free of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctxt` maps to an [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring); an Objective-C Foundation.framework encoding of a string.

> **NSString** : Internally, Cocoa scripting always uses Unicode text when converting to get information from or add it to an Apple event.

You can find a reference to this type in Apple's [Cocoa Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_about_apps/SAppsAboutApps.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Graham Miln has answered my question, but I found this explanation if anyone wanted additional info:

> There is not a practical difference between both "string" and "text" terms, concerning AppleScript.
>
> However, there are some "theoretical" differences:
>
> - *String* is some Mac-Roman text (Mac ASCII, 8-bit).
> - *Text* can contain language and styles.
>
> The main difference between "text" and "string" belongs to application developers, since they can define their own "type" ("TEXT" for string, "ctxt" for text) when they pass texts to AppleScript (eg, they can pass style information, as the clipboard, only Mac-ASCII characters, as Tex-Edit Plus, or even Unicode text -another kind of text-, as the Finder).

Source:

[MacScripter.net / *What is the difference between "string" and "text"?*](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24474)